# Launch Citrix 7.6 Storefront Published App Programmatically

Tags: c#, citrix

I've been looking through tons of forum posts and documentation, but I can not find out how to authenticate/launch an app published through a Citrix 7.6 Storefront interface programmatically (preferably in C#).  I'm extremely new to working with Citrix so any help would be appreciated.

At my company, we currently have a launcher like I described that works with Citrix 6.5 Web Interface, but we get generic errors when we attempt to use the same technique with 7.6 Storefront.

Can anyone provide me with a sample application doing what I want or point me towards an appropriate SDK/Documentation resource?  I would be EXCEPTIONALLY grateful for any assistance!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Very very old post but since I was struggling as well, here's some pointers that works well with StoreFront 3.5.

First of all, the following code works with the StoreFront web api and basic HTTP authentication. You must first do this on the StoreFront server to enabled the authentication with the following code:

- Open Citrix StoreFront
- Click on "Manage Authentication Method"
- Check the box "Basic HTTP"

Here's a class that you can drop in that will work given that you install the following nuget packages:

- RestSharp
- JSON.NET

[WebApi C# Sample](https://gist.github.com/omniscient/b99a38f6d8f7f39a739e4ccf99c7b9b0#file-program-cs)

(Sorry I wasn't able to past the code directly here because of formatting)

The sample can be copy/pasted into a console application. I have written and cleaned up the code such that anyone can understand and use it.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the Receiver 4.0 you can use the Receivers -qlaunch parameter.
See the Citrix dokumentation https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX200337
SelfService.exe –qlaunch “appname” is the command and you can use the process start command in c# to launch the application by name.
I hope this will also help as a simple solution.

Regards Bernd